# Not getting something with a regex

Tags: php, regex

I attempted to [answer this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929356/php-query-string-manipulation/3929390#3929390) (answer deleted, so here is my code).

```
<?php
function remove_get_param($uri, $name) {  
        return preg_replace('/(?<=\?|&|;)' . preg_quote($name, '/') . '=[^&;]*/', '', $uri);     
}
```

My initial code was consuming the first param such as `?` when it shouldn't. I tried to do a lookbehind assertion but PHP said...

> Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 11 on line 4

I'm relatively new with regex assertions, but I assumed that a *lookbehind assertion* means *make sure this pattern precedes, but don't consume it as part of the match*.

I looked up the syntax by googling *regex cheetsheat* and the resulting PNG I downloaded said that the syntax was `?<=`.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

### Update

Hello again. Here is some example usage that caused the warning above twice...

```
echo remove_get_param('http://mysite.com?param1=1&param2=2', 'param2') . "\n";
echo remove_get_param('http://mysite.com?param1=1&param2=2', 'param1');
```

I should also mention I got these errors on [codepad.org](http://codepad.org/JV4YdLS5). Sorry for failing to mention that, I know codepad.org runs in a funky environment.

Comment: I'm not getting this warning when running this function in my PHP shell, though I'm not certain that the shell outputs warnings… EDIT: ran `error_reporting(E_ALL)` first, too. Function seems to run as expected in PHP5. What are your input strings?

Comment: do you happen to have a "/" character in `$name`?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? 5.2.6 works fine.

Comment: Ok, sorry guys, I'll supply test data.

Comment: After the barrage of downvotes from the OP of the original question. You got out well deleting your answer :)

Comment: @Jason I knew there was a reason for it! :D

Comment: @thetaiko: good catch, and that throws a warning, but it's an "unknown modifier" warning. There's apparently another issue here, too.

Comment: Your two sample lines throw no errors for me in PHP 5.3.3.

Comment: Wait, should I be using `preg_quote($name, '/')` ?

Comment: @alex: oh, wow, didn't even know that that second parameter was there. Yes. Yes you should :) A slash in the param name is unlikely, but let's not make that assumption yet.

Comment: @alex - only if there is a "/" character in your params, which it looks like there aren't.

Comment: No warnings for me - PHP 5.3.2. However, the function does leave the & in the resulting url.

Comment: Your codepad code has an extra asterisk (after the lookbehind, at offset 11)! :P

Comment: @Tim: Holy moly! I knew it would be something stupid... I'll accept if you *answerise* that comment :D

Comment: Also - append `.?` to the end of the regex to remove not necessary query parameters delimiter

Comment: @zerkms: There you are again! :P Sorry to be confused, but can you explain your comment in some more detail? You mean just to clean up any extraneous garbage that may be there?

Comment: @Match (refer to deleted answer) You are a true gentleman!

Comment: `preg_replace('~(?<=\?|&|;)' . preg_quote($name, '~') . '=[^&;]*.?~', '', $uri)`. That is what I meant. The `.?` part will remove `&`s right after removed name-value pair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code which you were [testing on Codepad](http://codepad.org/JV4YdLS5) has an additional asterisk after the lookbehind:

```
return preg_replace('/(?!=\?|&|;)*' . preg_quote($name) . '=[^&;]/', '', $uri);
                              // ^-- problem character
```

Since there is nothing for the 0 or more repetition to be applied to, the regular expression compilation fails with the mentioned error. It looks like that asterisk was the one you meant to be present at the end of the expression, as seen in the example in your question.

Comment: @alex: Heh, it happens to all of us. This is actually the third typo-related answer I've given this week. :)